# fastest autocomplete out there

Tags: javascript, database, jquery, autocomplete

So there are a lot of autocompletes out there.

What i want to achieve is an autocomplete that can work with database (i.e load results on runtime since i can't afford to preload 1 million results )

Typeahead.js caught my eye but the repository is dead ? also autocomplete.js also caught my eye which is fairly new, its for a big project so i don't want to use something that i will regret

so in short i need an autocomplete that is fast, customizable and not too hard too use

Comment: First of all, this is not possible to do exclusively on the front-end (i.e. with jQuery) because the back-end *matters*. Like, a lot. If you want to do extremely fast autocomplete on *millions* of records (or more), you need back-end infrastructure to support it. I would recommend changing your question to allow for those more complete solutions rather than jQuery-only solutions, as those are almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: This may be a good usage case for Lazy Loading: [https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary-lazy-loading/](https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary-lazy-loading/)